# Rails time_select param brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a `time_select` in Rails. According to the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select) the first argument should be an object_name, and the second the method name. This doesn't make much sense to me.

I am using it in conjunction with `form_for`, so I am passing in my model name as the first argument, and my field name as second:

```
form.time_select :base_content, :start_at, { ...
```

Which produces the following exception: `undefined method 'merge' for :start_at:Symbol`

But if I just pass in the field name:

```
form.time_select :start_at, { ...
```

It works fine. But now I have another problem, the param comes out as:

```
start_at(5i)
```

What is `(5i)` and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: what is the column name the the time is stored under in the db? is it `base_content` or `start_at` or something else?

Comment: do you have a gem like `combined_time_select` installed?

Comment: I do yes. Thanks, that must be why. Confusing they choose the same name as the original method.

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi: Post your comment as an answer and I will accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right with the second way. The `5i` is to mark that the parameter is the minutes value, `4i` would be hours. But the gem [`combined_time_select`](https://github.com/excid3/combined_time_select) that you have installed overrides the `time_select` method to put the whole time in one parameter - for some reason it chooses to keep the `(5i)` on the end of the parameter name.

In the controller you should use the method `parse_time_select` method to parse the parameter before using it to update the model

```
params[:base_content].parse_time_select! :start_time
```